# How do I disable Aero transparency in Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox, aero

I noticed that the transparent interface in Firefox 4 for Windows 7 is really curbing performance. After Googling for a method to disable Aero for Firefox, however, I got no results. There just doesn't seem to be a straight forward (such as a simple Boolean to turn it off in `about:config`) method to get rid of Aero effects.

Is it even possible in the Firefox 4 beta? I'm using Firefox 4 beta 12 (soon to be RC after the update).

Comment: btw @Titus you might want to upgrade to Firefox 4 RC

Comment: Thanks for the heads up; I meant RC (After all the beta X updates, I kept thinking the next one was 13!)
:D

Comment: Updated my question to say RC instead of beta 13.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable Aero when you run FireFox by setting it's Windows compatibility options and check-marking "Disable Desktop Composition".  But this will turn of Aero system-wide when you run FF.

There are others finding this problem as well, and it seems to be related to the new hardware acceleration in FF4, [as witnessed at mozillazine.org's forums](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=1973567&start=15).

Testing suggestions from [here](http://blog.mozilla.com/joe/2010/09/15/testing-hardware-acceleration/):

> To test if a problem you’re seeing is due to hardware acceleration, you can disable it. There are two ways to accomplish this:
>
> •Run Firefox in safe mode. (All hardware acceleration is always disabled in safe mode.)
>
> •Uncheck “Use hardware acceleration when available” in the Advanced section of the Preferences/Options dialog.

Comment: Thanks techie007! I'll look into it when I get home. Yes, hardware acceleration might be it; my laptop is a piece of crap. Also, thanks for the links. I hope the mozillaline.org forum will get fixed soon.

Answer (score 2):

To dispose of Aero in Firefox, use a persona - say, Vista Aero Firefox or Brushed. I hate the way Aero hinders reading the menus.

Comment: I've found "Wongs OS Integration Theme" to be an excellent choice for Windows 7. http://www.getpersonas.com/en-US/persona/78780

Comment: @Starfish That is a great and simple solution. Thanks!